# How to update ProgressBar in a List Activity using Adapter

Tags: android, progress-bar, listactivity

```
public class ChallengesActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        printTripsToScreen(); 
        setContentView(R.layout.challenge_list);
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.challenge_row, 
                new String[] {"description","progress"},
                new int[] {R.id.ch_description, R.id.ch_progress});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void printTripsToScreen() {
           Log.d("Carbon","ChallengesActivity: printTripsToScreen() started");
           ChallengeManager chManager = new ChallengeManager();
           ArrayList<Challenge> challenges = chManager.getChallenges();
           HashMap<String,String> temp;

           for (int i=0; i<challenges.size();i++){
               temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
               temp.put("description","Hello");
               temp.put("progress", ""+challenges.get(i).getCompleted_percentage());
               list.add(temp);
           }
       }
}
```

I need to update the value in progress bar. I'm using a adapter and HashMap to update text content. How to update the values in progressbar? If this is not the way please let me know how to doit?. The list is dynamic.

Comment: You question is not clear. How to update the `ProgressBar`? From where?

Comment: from ListActivity. The text "description" is updated using an ArrayList of HashMap called list. But using the same thing i cannot update the progress bar. It gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Progressbar` in the row of the `ListView` and you want to update its progress(with a value you already have) you could use a `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` to bind the values for that `ProgressBar`. Bellow is an example that resets the `ProgressBar`(from that row) to `0` when you click a `ListView` row:

```
    //...
    //I assumed that you have a ProgressBar in the ListView row with the id progressBar1
    // and you use the the value from the "progress" key as its progress.
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                    R.layout.someclasses_challaenge_row, new String[] {
                            "description", "progress", "progress"}, new int[] {
                            R.id.ch_description, R.id.ch_progress, R.id.progressBar1});
            adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                        String textRepresentation) {
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.progressBar1) {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
                        ((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(value);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            setListAdapter(adapter);

    @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> item = list.get(position);
            item.put("progress", "0");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I don't know if this is what you wanted.